# List of header file locations for the Havok Physics Engine

Tags: c++, physics-engine, havok

I am trying to integrate the Havok physics engine into my small game. It is a really nice SDK, but the header files are all over the place. Many headers are deeply nested in multiple directories. That gets confusing when you are trying to include headers for different important objects.

I would like to know if there is a nice guide that will let you know where certian objects are and what headres they are in. I have already looked at Havok's documentation, and I also looked at the reference manual, but they don't give great detail as to where certain classes are located (header location). Also, is there any programs out there that can scan header files and create a list of where objects can be found?

Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Visual Studio, right-clicking on a class and selecting `Go to Declaration` usually does a good job of finding the header. You can could also add the source directory to your list of directories to search for `Find in Files`. Once you've got the header open, you can copy the file path and convert it to a #include statement.

FYI, in general, this [forum on Intel's site](http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/havok/) is a better place than SO for Havok-specific questions. I check there regularly, as do several of the developer support engineers from Havok.